# 'End of statement expected' erro no pyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Tenho um método bem simples, que recebe um parâmetro booleano e altera uma global para o valor negado do parâmetro.
Porém, utilizando a IDE PyCharm, ela retorna um erro no trecho `global state = not x`

```
state = False

def change_state(x):
    global state = not x
```

[image: erros que aparecem no pycharm]

O que significa esse erro? Qual seria a forma correta do código?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que a atribuição do valor da variável global está na mesma linha.

O correto seria assim:

```
state = False

def change_state(x):
    global state
    state = not x
    print(state)

change_state(state)
```

Resultado:

```
True
```